# Objective-C NSString isEqualToString not getting match

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

If I have an array created like so:

```
NSArray* arrItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];
```

and I have a class with a NSString property:

```
myClass.myClassString = @"One";
```

shouldn't isEqualToString work if I do this:

```
NSString* strToCheck = myClass.myClassString

for(int i=0; i<arrItems.count; i++) {

    NSString* strThisItem = [arrItems objectAtIndex:i]; 

    if ([strThisItem isEqualToString:strToCheck]) { 
       NSLog(@"Okley dokley!");
    }

}
```

Edit:

Real World results:

In my app I am not getting a match even - this is my log out put with both strings and their length - look at where Safety Marketing is matching up - there should be a "OK" also logged here.

```
2013-08-28 09:20:02.339 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_7::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.341 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_7::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.341 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_7::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.342 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_7::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
2013-08-28 09:20:02.342 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_9::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.343 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_9::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.343 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_9::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.344 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_9::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
2013-08-28 09:20:02.344 oer[3081:c07] Competitor_10::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.345 oer[3081:c07] Competitor_10::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.345 oer[3081:c07] Competitor_10::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.345 oer[3081:c07] Competitor_10::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
2013-08-28 09:20:02.346 oer[3081:c07] Safety_Marketing_16::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.346 oer[3081:c07] Safety_Marketing_16::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.347 oer[3081:c07] Safety_Marketing_16::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.347 oer[3081:c07] Safety_Marketing_16::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
2013-08-28 09:20:02.348 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_Marketing_19::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.348 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_Marketing_19::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.349 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_Marketing_19::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.349 oer[3081:c07] Acecide-C_Marketing_19::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
2013-08-28 09:20:02.350 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_Marketing_17::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.350 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_Marketing_17::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.351 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_Marketing_17::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.351 oer[3081:c07] ALDAHOL_Marketing_17::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
2013-08-28 09:20:02.352 oer[3081:c07] OER-Pro Service_Marketing_25::Safety Marketing_16
2013-08-28 09:20:02.352 oer[3081:c07] OER-Pro Service_Marketing_25::Acecide-C Marketing_19
2013-08-28 09:20:02.353 oer[3081:c07] OER-Pro Service_Marketing_25::ALDAHOL Marketing_17
2013-08-28 09:20:02.353 oer[3081:c07] OER-Pro Service_Marketing_25::OER-Pro Service Marketing_25
```

Comment: Dag nabbit - I see my mistake - the underscores...crap. : D

Comment: yes, rm the question maybe!?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that should work.
Perhaps myClass.myClassString is not getting the value you want before the isEqualToString check.

NSLogs printing myClass.myClassString, strToCheck and arrItems should help you find where it goes wrong.

Now I saw your edit:

Safety_Marketing_16   <- two underscores

Safety Marketing_16   <- one underscore

;)

(thank you very much! :D )

Comment: I gave you points for the effort. : D